# How do I resize a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

Suppose I had a **1-by-12** matrix and I wanted to resize it to a **4-by-3** matrix. How could I do this?

My current solution is kind of ugly:

```
for n = 1:(length(mat)/3)
    out(n,1:3) = mat( ((n-1)*3 + 1):((n-1)*3 + 3) );
end
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`reshape` is of course the proper solution, as stated by [@gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/793581/5211833).

A nice feature of `reshape` is that it allows this:

```
A = 1:12;
B = reshape(A,4,[]);
B =
     1     5     9
     2     6    10
     3     7    11
     4     8    12
```

So if you don't know how many columns there will be, `reshape` will compute it for you. Likewise, `reshape` will fill in the number of rows, if you leave that out.

```
C = reshape(A,[],4)
C =
     1     4     7    10
     2     5     8    11
     3     6     9    12
```

Comment: +1: Nice! I actually never noticed that before. I guess I never had to use it.

Answer (score 12):

Try the [RESHAPE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html) function:

```
A = (1-by-12 matrix);
B = reshape(A,4,3);
```

Note that the matrix **B** will be filled with elements from **A** in a columnwise fashion (i.e. columns will be filled from top to bottom, moving left to right).

Example:

```
>> A = 1:12;
>> B = reshape(A,4,3)

B =

     1     5     9
     2     6    10
     3     7    11
     4     8    12
```

Comment: Note that the reshape returns an error if A doesn't have exactly 4*3 elements.

Comment: Yes, that is the normal expected behavior of RESHAPE.

Comment: Can't we tell RESHAPE to add zeros if there are no exactly 4*3 elements? I meant if there are less than 12 elements.

Comment: @Nadeeshani: No, but you *can* do this instead: `A = 1:11; B = zeros(4,3); B(1:numel(A)) = A;`

Comment: @gnovice `A = 1:11; B = zeros(4,3); B(1:numel(A)) = A;` Does this columnwise?

Comment: @Boggartfly: Yes, that will fill `B` columnwise. If you want to fill rowwise, I would do this: `A = 1:11; B = zeros(3,4); B(1:numel(A)) = A; B = B.';`

Answer (score 9):

to extend gnovice's solution:

If you need a different order of matrix construction, use transpose (the ' operator) or [`permute()`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/permute.html) to change the dimension ordering after you have called `reshape()`.

Comment: +1: Good point about transposing and PERMUTE. These are sometimes needed after a reshape.