# Matlab: how do I change the way a matrix is stored? from 1x1x3 to 1x3?

Tags: matlab

I currently have:

```
val(:,:,1) =

    0.7216

val(:,:,2) =

    0.7216

val(:,:,3) =

    0.7216
```

But I want

```
0.7216, 0.716, 0.721.
```

What sort of operation can I do to do that?

Comment: The numbers you want don't actually match the values in val, is this a mistake or is there some other processing required.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resize a matrix in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793574/how-do-i-resize-a-matrix-in-matlab)

Comment: Agreed similar question but subtle differences, the mentioned duplicate is talking about reshaping a matrix, whereas this is more about removing dimensions. OK you can argue it's the same thing but for anyone searching for an answer they are likely to be asking slightly different questions so may not find the resize question. Perhaps the duplicate question could be updated to cover "both" scenarios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `reshape` function will do the trick here:

```
% Arrange the elements of val into a 1x3 array
val = reshape(val, [1 3]);
```

Because you are converting to a row-vector, the following syntax will also work:

```
val = val(:)';
```

Because `val(:)` creates a column-vector, and the transpose operator `'` then transposes that column-vector into a row-vector.

Answer (score 4):

The function [squeeze](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/squeeze.html) is another option if you have a varying number of elements in the third dimension

```
>> squeeze(val)'
ans =
    0.7216    0.7216    0.7216
```

assuming that you want these numbers - the required numbers in your question don't actually match the values from the matrix val.

Answer (score 1):

```
val = val(:)';
```

This should do the trick.

`(:)` will convert it to a column.

`'` will transpose it to a row

Comment: val = val(:); will create a 3x1 column-vector, not the 1x3 row-vector the question is after.