# Change 3-column data into matrix form for 2D plot

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have my data in 3 columns, denoting the values of the x, y and z coordinates respectively. The x and y points are on a grid (may be non-uniform, as here):

```
x y z 

1 1 5
1 2 7
1 3 0
3 1 6
3 2 9
3 3 5
7 1 4
7 2 0
7 3 8
```

Now I want to use a MATLAB function like `pcolor` to make a 2D color plot of this data where the `z` values will be denoted by color. Unfortunately `pcolor` wants the data for the `x` and `y` coordinates either as vectors or as grid matrices, and the `z` data also in the form of a grid matrix, and will not except column data of this form.

I don't want to use any fitting or interpolation. I only want to rearrange the data I have here. How can I attain this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resize a matrix in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/793574/how-do-i-resize-a-matrix-in-matlab). Your own answer to your question makes me think that the duplicate is valid.

Comment: @AndrasDeak whilst if his data is not in this fantastically simply `[x,y]` structure, you'd need something else entirely to make `pcolor` work, see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34728289/5211833)

Comment: Note that you don't (and shouldn't) put the language name in your title like that: that's what tags are for!

Answer (score 3):

General purpose method using [`meshgrid`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) and [`unique`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html):

```
data = [1 1 5;
1 2 7;
1 3 0;
3 1 6;
3 2 9;
3 3 5;
7 1 4;
7 2 0;
7 3 8];
[tmpX1,~,tmpX3] = unique(data(:,1));
[tmpY1,~,tmpY3] = unique(data(:,2));
[X,Y] = meshgrid(tmpX1,tmpY1);
tmpZ = sub2ind(tmpX3,tmpY3); %// use the third output from unique as indices
Z = zeros(size(X)); %//preallocate Z
Z(tmpZ) = data(:,3); %// Use indices to fill the grid
pcolor(X,Y,Z)
```

The third output of `unique` can be used as an integer representation of the location within the `[X,Y]` grid. [`sub2ind`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) function courtesy of [András Deák](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5067311/andras-deak)

As opposed to [@AbhranilDas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34727762/5211833) this solution works also if your data is not on a nice grid, e.g.

```
data = [1 1 5;
5 2 7;
1 3 0;
3 1 6;
3 2 9;
3 7 5;
7 1 4;
7 2 0;
4 3 8];
```

The OP's solution only works because the data when reshaped through column-major order becomes exactly the coordinate grids as output by `meshgrid`. Whenever your data is not that simple and nice, using `reshape` will get you a non-uniform coordinate matrix.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for plotting purposes, where run-time performance is not a concern, I wouldn't resort to any fancy indexing trickery that's hard to understand and maintain.

Instead, I'd like to recommend a good old for loop combined with imagesc:

```
data = [
1 1 5
1 2 7
1 3 0
3 1 6
3 2 9
3 3 5
7 1 4
7 2 0
7 3 8
];

plt_data = NaN(max(data(:,2)), max(data(:,1)));

% iterate over the rows
for xyz = data'
    plt_data(xyz(2), xyz(1)) = xyz(3);
end

imagesc(plt_data)
colorbar()
```

[image]

Okay, so if you have data with negative axis points, then it becomes more work:

```
data = [
1 -1 5
1 2 7
1 -3 1
3 1 6
-3 2 9
-3 -3 5
7 1 4
7 -2 1
7 3 8
];

x0 = min(data(:,1));
x1 = max(data(:,1));

y0 = min(data(:,2));
y1 = max(data(:,2));

xrange = x1 - x0;
yrange = y1 - y0;

plt_data = NaN(yrange, xrange);

% iterate over the rows
for xyz = data'
    plt_data(xyz(2)-y0+1, xyz(1)-x0+1) = xyz(3);
end

imagesc(x0:x1, y0:y1, plt_data)
set(gca(), 'ydir', 'normal')
colorbar()
```

And you'll probably want to flip the y-axis so it looks like a familiar Cartesian axis:

[image]

Comment: Note that this only works when the `[x,y]` coordinates are positive integers.

Comment: I added a case for negative coordinates

Comment: What about non-integers? Like `(3.5, 2.3, 4)` as a coordinate? Regardless of that, for the exact data the OP provides, your solution works fine. No idea whether his actual data is more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

```
X=reshape(data(:,1), [3 3]);
Y=reshape(data(:,2), [3 3]);
Z=reshape(data(:,3), [3 3]);

pcolor(X,Y,Z);
```

Note: this will produce a matrix with 4 colours instead of nine because `pcolor` drops a row and column, but that's a different issue.